# Randomly Order Array Recursive with Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am currently developing a BlackJack app in Java, and i have to shufle the Deck in a recursive way

I have already tryed it with for but my professor said the right way is to do it recursive

```
public void shuffle() {
        ArrayList<Card> colCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        Random  random = new Random();
        int randomIndex =0; 
        int lenght = this.cards.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
              randomIndex = random.nextInt(this.cards.size()-1-0)+0);

                        colCards.add(this.cards.get(randomIndex));
                        this.cards.remove(randomIndex)

        }
                this.cards = colCards;

}
```

This is currently working , but i am looking for a way to do it recursive

Comment: First step would be to attempt to refactor the loop out and when you face a specific problem with making it recursive you can ask a specific question.

Comment: Why `-0` and `+0`?

Comment: Just for the record: consider to ask your professor to ask him *why* recursive is the "right" way. Dont just accept authority, he, too, should be able to explain why recursive is "better". When an assignment says "use recursion", fine, then that is the assignment. But a statement "it is better that way" is fair to be questioned.

Comment: Recursion allocates memory for method every time it is called so saying it is always better is not correct. Think about it

Comment: The objective was to use recursion

Comment: If the objective was an exercise in recursive programming, that's one thing.  But shuffling values is easy and using recursion is probably not the best way.  If making repeated method calls was efficient, then inlining methods would never be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a very expensive operation comparing to a simple loop. And if you have a choice between recursion and a loop, go for the loop, since it will be faster and you will never have stack overflow.

However, if the goal is to do solve the problem using recursion this is the way:

```
public List<Object> shuffle(List<Object> cards, int pos) {
    if (pos == cards.size() - 2)
        return cards;

    Object card = cards.get(pos);

    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        cards.set(pos, cards.get(pos + 1));
        cards.set(pos + 1, card);
    } else if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        if (pos != 0) {
            cards.set(pos, cards.get(pos - 1));
            cards.set(pos - 1, card);
        } else {
            cards.set(pos, cards.get(pos + 1));
            cards.set(pos + 1, card);
        }
    }

    return shuffle(cards, ++pos);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will randomly swap previous or next card with the current card (if it not the first or last operation), until the of the list will not be reached.

Comment: @IlyaSerebryannikov How do I invoke your method?  When I try `shuffle(values, 0)` it doesn't properly shuffle the cards.  Other numbers either throw an exception or do  even less of  a shuffle.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because I don't believe it works properly.  At a minimum, the last value never changes its position.  Other values near each other seem to be simply swapped.  Nor do I know exactly how to invoke the method.  I presume it starts with 0 as the initial position.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way which lends itself to any object type.  But there is nothing gained by recursion as the repeated method calls simply take the place of a loop.

```java
   public <T> void shuffle(List<T> values, int n) {
      if (n == 0) {
         return;
      }
      int d = (int) (Math.random() * (n-1));
      T c = values.get(n - 1);
      values.set(n - 1, values.get(d));
      values.set(d, c);
      shuffle(values, n - 1);
   }
```

Moving the value from some random location `k` where `0 <= k < n-1` to location `n-1`. Each time thru, `n` is reduced by `1`.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that you are using n to count makes it a loop?

Comment: Nope.  Because it isn't really looping.  It is building up on the call stack and then returning in reverse order. When it does, `n` increases in value due to previous values on the call stack.  To see this, print out `n` `after` the recursive call to shuffle.  The `n's` will return to their previous values.  And decrementing a value in this way is common to many recursive routines.  One classic example is computing factorials.